# How to list the users in the AD group on the Google Cloud Platform gcloud command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I need to run a Schedule job to check the existence of the certain user in the AD Group sync in Google Cloud Platform. Any gcloud command or any Google Cloud Platform API that I can call?

Comment: Are you using hybrid active directory or managed Microsoft AD or federation ... Edit your question with details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using managed service Microsoft AD on GCP, maybe you can use this [API](https://cloud.google.com/managed-microsoft-ad/reference/rest) , because it's still in [beta version](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/now-in-beta-managed-service-for-microsoft-active-directory-ad) and also if you want to manage the AD object you can use this [option](https://cloud.google.com/managed-microsoft-ad/docs/manage-active-directory-objects).

Another alternative is if you are using hybrid cloud, you can take this solution by Google about how to set up account synchronization between AD and Cloud Identity by using [Google Cloud Directory Sync](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/federating-gcp-with-active-directory-synchronizing-user-accounts) (GCDS) as Gsuite product. GCDS uses sync-cmd to run synchronizations from the [command line](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6152425?hl=en&ref_topic=6152423).

Tell me if this information work for you, otherwise share more details